# StructureMap with two initializers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I have 3 projects.

```
  1
 / \   - inheritance
2   3
```

1 project has ObjectFactory.Initialize...
And I have 1 interface and two implementations.
I want use two different implementation for 2 and 3 projects.
What i should to do?
Is it possible using StructureMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution finded.
In base project I should to initialize:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x...)
```

But in depended project i should to configure after base project initialization:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x...)
```

Answer (score 1):

StructureMap is not the limiting factor here.  Which project(s) do your 2 interface implementations live in?

If they are in project 2 and 3 then you need to do your ObjectFactory.Initialize in projects 2 and 3 where you know which implementation of the interface you want to use.

If they are in project 1, you could create two new classes in project 1 that initialize a container in the way that is needed by project 2 and 3 and then make sure the proper class is used for each respective project.

In both scenarios, you need two different ways to build up the container to support the end result, which is project 2 and 3 in your case.

Comment: I have add initializers to my 2 and 3 projects. Now it work like this: 

- Execute base initializator;

- Execute initializator for 2 or 3 projects;

But it throw exception if i try to do something that use any implementation defined in base initializator.
If I reverse invoking it throw exception for implementation from  "initializator for project".

Comment: Can you edit your post and show your base initializer and the initializer for project 2 or 3?  Also, can you show your example that is throwing the exception when you use an implementation in the base initializer?